# Mutable variables in closures in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to port some code form java do F# that generates a grid of multidimensional points around a given point. I came up with this:

```
let gridGenerator midpoint stepSize steps = 
    seq {
        let n = Array.length midpoint
        let direction = Array.create n -steps
        let mutable lastIndex = n-1
        while lastIndex>=0 do
            let next = midpoint |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> x+ direction.[i]*stepSize)
            while lastIndex>=0 && direction.[lastIndex]=steps do 
                direction.[lastIndex]<- (-steps)
                lastIndex<-lastIndex-1;        
            if lastIndex>=0 then
                direction.[lastIndex]<-direction.[lastIndex]+1;
                lastIndex <- n-1;
            yield next;
    }
```

Apart from this code being horribly imperative (I would be grateful for hints how to fix it), I am getting a compilation error:

> Program.fs(18,15): error FS0407: The mutable variable 'lastIndex' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures. Consider eliminating this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell via 'ref' and '!'.

How can I fix this error? How can I make it more functional?

EXAMPLE: For midpoint `[|0.0, 1.0|]`, step size `0.5` and steps `1` I expect (in any order really)

```
seq{[|-0.5, 0.5|], [|-0.5, 1.0|], [|-0.5, 1.5|], [|0.0, 0.5|], [|0.0, 1.0|], [|0.0, 1.5|], [|0.5, 0.5|], [|0.5, 1.0|], [|0.5, 1.5|]}
```

Please also note that this will be executed many times, so performance is critical.

Comment: "Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures." Serious design WTF for F#.

Comment: Because you are using `yield`, I doubt you will be able to rewrite this more functionally.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do: use [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx).

Comment: @leppie - this avoids a whole class of subtle bugs that can happen in C# - see for example [eric lipperts blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: @JohnPalmer: If I needed handholding, I would use VB ;p

Comment: @JohnPalmer: That article deals specifically with 'broken' C# constructs. I dont see how it is applicable to F#.

Comment: @leppie If you don't need handholding, why not code in C++?  Better yet code in assembly--no handholding there.

Comment: @leppie, see http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/on-lambdas-capture-and-mutability/ for design rationale.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: C++ and assembly is hardly functional.

Comment: @Brian: I understand the choice you have to make, but to me, that is a compiler detail. I dont understand why the user has to be burdened with it, iow use boxes (`ref` in F#) or make a compiler error. Why can this not be transparent to the user? I personally think F# took this 'read-only' thing a bit far :) Also rememeber, functional code is the hands of the user, not the compiler. Both answers given hardly represent a functional style and relies on a pretty much 'iterative' approach. Also, I am confused why `while/do` creates a closure, where `for` does not. Thanks for link :)

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, that last observation is unfounded. But I am interested now :)  Does `while/do` create a closure, where `for` does not?

Comment: @leppie: this is an extremely common mistake in every language, and I think it is the responsibility of the compiler to warn you of the ambiguity and force you to be explicit/intentional about it.  None of `for`/`while`/`do` create a closure.  In the OP's example, it is `seq{}` that creates the closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let gridGenerator midpoint stepSize steps =
    seq {
        let n = Array.length midpoint
        let direction = Array.create n -steps
        let lastIndex = ref (n - 1)
        while !lastIndex >= 0 do
            let next = midpoint |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> x + direction.[i] * stepSize)
            while !lastIndex >= 0 && direction.[!lastIndex] = steps do
                direction.[!lastIndex] <- -steps
                decr lastIndex
            if !lastIndex >= 0 then
                direction.[!lastIndex] <- direction.[!lastIndex] + 1
                lastIndex := n - 1
            yield next
    }
```

?

`ref`'s are very good for such uses, and are not considered mutable variables (because they are not).

Comment: So `ref` is just a box (in functional terminology)?

Comment: Compiles. But why does it have type int everywhere? I thought F# was supposed to be able to generalize types, and not guess int?

Comment: 0 and 1 are of type `int`, also the default `decr` function works only with `int`'s. I also think array indices must be integers (a fault in the .NET framework design).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more functional way of doing it:

```
let rec gridGenerator midpoint stepSize steps =
    match midpoint with
    | [] -> Seq.singleton []
    | p::point ->
        seq {
            for d in - stepSize * steps .. stepSize .. stepSize * steps do
                for q in gridGenerator point stepSize steps do
                    yield (p + d) :: q
        }
```

And the signature:

```
val gridGenerator : int list -> int -> int -> seq<int list>
```

If you reuse the result, remember to cache it or convert it (to an array or a list).

Answer (score 3):

Now you can just use F# 4, which doesn't have such constraint.